# Customising a JS data object to suit

Tags: javascript, date

I was wondering if it's possible to customise the `e.data.date` to a string output that's more suited to my needs. Currently, `e.data.date`, for example, would output as `Thu Jun 2012 2014 2000:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)` but ideally I'd like to to replicate the event start and end date input of `20140607`.

`e.data.date` is a [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

I could use `e.data.date.getUTCDate()` to get the month for example, but to get the desired output of `20141102`, for example, which includes year, month and date, there doesn't seem to be a getter method...

Any ideas?

Comment: easy way: new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0].split("-").join("")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date.prototype.GetCustomFormat = function ()
{
    return this.getFullYear()+""+getInTwoDigitFormat(Number(this.getMonth())+1)+""+getInTwoDigitFormat(Number(this.getDay())-1);

};

function getInTwoDigitFormat(val)
{
    return val < 10 ? '0' + val : val;
}
```

and you can call it like `new Date().GetCustomFormat();`

Update 24 sep, 2014:

```
Date.prototype.format = function (format) 
{
    var o = {
        "M+": this.getMonth() + 1,
        "d+": this.getDate(),   
        "h+": this.getHours(),   
        "m+": this.getMinutes(), 
        "s+": this.getSeconds(), 
        "q+": Math.floor((this.getMonth() + 3) / 3), 
        "S": this.getMilliseconds() 
    };

    if (/(y+)/.test(format)) format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
      (this.getFullYear() + "").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
    for (var k in o) if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format))
        format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
          RegExp.$1.length == 1 ? o[k] :
            ("00" + o[k]).substr(("" + o[k]).length));
    return format;
};
```

In this way you can format any date how you want faster than implementing a custom library.
For example:

```
x=new Date();
Date {Wed Sep 24 2014 14:30:22 GMT+0300 (GTB Standard Time)}
x.format('M')
"9"
x.format('d')
"24"
x.format('d M')
"24 9"
x.format('d:M')
"24:9"
x.format('d:MM')
"24:09"
x.format('d:MM:yy')
"24:09:14"
x.format('d:MM:yyy')
"24:09:014"
```

Comment: You about? Having used this... month and date seem to be wrong. What is `this`?

Comment: `this` is the value of the object ( in this case the Date type object ). So you can use any javascript date and use new function as part of it's properties to give you back the new string format .

Comment: `Date.getMonth` returns the month index, not the month. e.g. 0 = January.  Why reinvent the wheel? http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Cause reinventing the wheel gives you speed. Which is very important at this point. Even for 0.1 s I would choose to dump a script like momentjs and use my custom functions.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a little on @HellBaby's answer:

You can overwrite any default JS object property. You can overwrite the `toString` function in the `Date` prototype; that way any place that auto-parses your date as a string will use your custom function instead:

```
Date.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "Custom formatted date string";
};
```

eg. http://jsfiddle.net/x8f3S/

---

Now, keep in mind the above will overwrite the `toString` function for ALL dates in your script. If you only want to overwrite it for one particular date object you can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(e.data.date, "toString", {
    value: function() {
         return "Custom formatted date string";
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x8f3S/1/

---

You can even take this a step further, and define it for every `date` you set inside `e.data`:

```
Object.defineProperty(e.data, "date", {
    get: function() { /*...*/ }
    set: function(customDate) { /* modify customDate's prototype here */ }
}
```

Here's a demo of the last approach: http://jsfiddle.net/x8f3S/2/

---

Note these are all convenience methods. You can achieve exactly the same by using custom functions and callbacks.